# Storing unique images in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've inherited a database which contains .png images which have been converted `byte[]` and finally `ToBase64String` and saved in a table with many duplicate images. I want to clean this up create a new table with unique images but the original tables have no primary key related to the image. I've come up with the following idea but would like some feedback on viability or better suggestions.

i) Create new table with 2 columns

```
PrimaryKey varchar(64)
ImageBinary varbinary(MAX)
```

ii) Convert Base64String back to image byte[] and store in SQL as `ImageBinary varbinary(MAX)`

iii) Hash image using `HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', ImageBinary)` and store in SQL as `PrimaryKey varchar(64)`

iv) Any new images will be hashed and compared against existing primary key hashes.

Current stats approx

- Images in db approx 200,000
- Unique images in db 70,000
- Potential future unique images in db 1,000,000
- Current data character length of ToBase64String in SQL Min:2,900 Max: 170,000

Two main questions

1. The reason for hashing the image was I thought it may speed up checking for duplicates by comparing new image hash vs existing image hash. An alternative could be just compare the full image and use integer for primary key. Is it better to hash?
2. If hashing is preferred, I don't really need cryptographic hashing, what's the fastest/shortest hashing that can be used in SQL for this?

Comment: The bigger the block size, the faster the algorithm is, so MD5 is *slower* than SHA1 which is slower than SHA256. If you store images in the database you can't use any algorithm that isn't provided by the database anyway, so you can't use any non-cryptographic hash

Comment: Which version are you using? SQL Server 2017 added support for Python, which means you could use Python packages for hashing *or for image comparison* - in fact, Python was added to enable such ML scenarios. Using it as a generic extension mechanism is a bonus

Comment: It's SQL server 2016 on the server, it integrates with C# and I'm fine replicating the hashing between SQL/C# based on different encodings.

Comment: SQL Server 2016 gives you R, which also has packages for hashing and ML. SQLCLR is essentially .NET 3.5+ or .NET 4-: it doesn't understand Tasks or NuGet. I suspect it would be easier to find a CityHash or MurmurHash implementation in R than C#

Comment: Check [Data.HashFunction](https://github.com/brandondahler/Data.HashFunction/). It supports many hash algorithms BUT SQLCLR knows nothing about NuGet. You'd have to create your own SQLCLR project, add the NuGet packages and hope there are no incompatibilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would store an integer uid - if you need to join, comparing 4 bytes is way faster than 16 Bytes or more. You can still store a hash in addition, if you need it, and you can also put a unique constaint on the hash if the hash isn't the primary key.
2. I'd say MD5. [SHA-1 might be slightly faster](https://automationrhapsody.com/md5-sha-1-sha-256-sha-512-speed-performance/#:%7E:text=SHA%2D256%20is%20faster%20with,only%20when%20hashing%20small%20strings.&text=MD5%20is%207.6%25%20slower%20than,strings%20and%2020%25%20for%20longer.), but it uses more space (20 bytes instead of 16 PER HASH).

Finally, I wouldn't store 1 million files in the database. 
Have a look at [filestream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), that way you can access the image via the database, but it's stored outside the database. Otherwise, making database backups will become a problem.

Have a look at the filestream tutorial from Red-Gate: 
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/

Example for MD5:

```
SET IMG_MD5 = LOWER(SUBSTRING(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HashBytes('MD5', FIELD_NAME)), 3, 32) ) 
   ,IMG_SHA1 = sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA1', FIELD_NAME), 1, 0)
```

Comment: And SHA256 will be even faster, especially for larger files - the bigger the block, the faster the algorithm

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: Yea, but sha512 is 64 bytes, and sha256 is 32 bytes in hash size. If I had 1 million images, I'd optimize the hash size, not the speed, especially if the speed difference is not large. Besides, according to automationrhapsody, Sha256 and Sha512 are slower. I'd also test the specific implementations in SQL-server, to see which is fastest.